# Cannot figure out how to add an existing ASP.NET Solution to Github

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, github

I was planning to use TFS for my personal software projects I work on, with Visual Studio Team Services, however Microsoft some time ago changed Team Services to use DevOps instead of TFS, I wanted something where I could publish Visual Studio solutions to source control that is publicly viewable on the Internet, for example projects I am working on with an MIT open source license, and also have private repositories for my proprietary projects I am working on that are NOT open source.

After Microsoft bought GitHub, I was sure they were going to integrate GitHub with Visual Studio, and they did! I installed the GitHub extensions into my Visual Studio, and signed up for the $7 a month GitHub developer service, a good deal no doubt. I was planning to use public repositories for example solutions to show publicly to help me with new software gigs, and use private repositories for my projects I hope to make money from. GitHub seems like a good solution for this reason, with the Developer account you can have unlimited public and unlimited private repositories.

SO my problem started when I tried to add an already existing ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC solution to Github, the tutorial I found showed only how to create a new project in a new or existing GitHub repository, not how to add an existing Visual Studio solution, I found some examples of doing this from the command line, but I am sure there must be some way to do this with clicks of a mouse instead of a command line option. I would like to know how to add an existing Visual Studio solution to GitHub with clicks of a mouse.

Comment: Install SourceTree, this will provide the instructions. Alternatively, use git cli to `git remote add origin https://whatever.github.com/project`

Comment: @zaitsman, I'm quite sure that SourceTree won't be required here.

Comment: @Chris of course OP can use github plugin for VS :) i just don't like it and i know sourcetree will actually work for OP coz it prompts you to login with github creds and then add local repos...

Comment: For some reason Visual Studio keeps adding the existing solution to Git, but does not upload the files to GitHub to be available in the same repo on the website, I am a little disappointed in GitHub, I used it before with Komodo for PHP projects in 2014, and do not recall ever having this same problem at that time. really Visual Studio should be superior to Komodo!.with Microsofts armies of developers!

Comment: Ok now I know the solution thanks to the answer below, there is actually two ways to publish a repo to Github, with Visual Studio, and also Github Desktop is a good resource, thank you everyone for taking the time to help me with this!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This his how you'd do it with Visual Studio 2017.

The Team Explorer tab is where you'll manage much of this.

1) In the Solution Explorer tab right-click and **Add Solution to Source Control...**

2) Now it will show up in the list of Local Git Repositories on the Team Explorer tab

[image]

3) Click the plug and log into GitHub if you haven't yet done so.

4) Click the home icon then click Sync

[image]

5) Enter the name of the repo then press Publish.

[image]

6) Check the remote to verify the files have been pushed up to GitHub.

Comment: Ok this is actually what I was looking for, thank you so much for your answer, I was also able to do the same thing with GitHub Desktop, I never thought to click the SYNC option in Visual Studio, this helps out immensely :-)